# Text comments in sympy output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, sympy

I've searched for a few days looking for a clue on how to easily format text commentary into the output of sympy when running inside (say) a Jupyter notebook.

Simple example of what i've tried so far:

```
init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')
print("Here is an integral ")
Integral(expr1,x)
```

...which outputs a crappy looking text comment above the line with a pretty good looking integral expression.    Instead, I'm looking for a text comment that'd be included on the same line as the integral and present itself with better formatting instead of just "code block" font.  Ideally, there'd be some sort of "printf" style function; but I just not have been able to find it.

Answer (score 3):

If you like the default markdown rendering, you can use the `Markdown` function to render your commentary and equation just as it would appear in a markdown cell:

```
import sympy
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
alpha, beta, theta = sympy.symbols('alpha beta theta')
my_eq = sympy.cos(alpha - beta + theta)
display(
    Markdown(
        'Here is my equation: {}'.format(
            sympy.latex(my_eq, mode='inline')
        )
    )
)
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks!   Am still learning about Markdown and this was clearly a huge gap in my understanding of Jupyter.     Very much appreciate your comment.

Comment: I think this answer deserves to be the OP's answer.

Answer (score 1):

So after some more research, came up with a form of an answer.   Using a combination of "display" and "Math" with latex conversions and strings of raw Latex; you can get to a solution with something like this:

```
display(Math("{Let}\ omega\ be\ this \ thing" + latex(Neworder3poly)))
```

I could apologize for having not done enough research before posting a question that could have been answered by JFGI, but instead; i'll offer a slightly sarcastic  THANK YOU from the poster of this question to the poster of this answer (me).

;)

Comment: Feels like this simple subroutine might be useful to someone else:                        
def displayEquality(expr1, expr2):
    display(Math(latex(expr1) +  "\ =\ " + latex(expr2)))

Answer (score 0):

This shows a good latex representation:

```
import sympy
from sympy import init_printing, Integral, Symbol

x = Symbol('x')
expr1 = 2*x**2 + 3*x + 2

init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')
print("Here is an integral ")
Integral(expr1, x), sympy.integrate(expr1)
```

#### output:

[image]