# How to an extra string to the display of an object with "display" in Jupyter, using Python?

Tags: python, string, jupyter, display

I have a number of mathematical objects created with SymPy, which display fine in Jupyter using "display".  For example, there are a number of functions which I can display with:

```
display(f1(x))
display(f2(x))
```

and so on.  But what I want is to prefix each line with some explanatory text, so the output is, for example:

Question 1:  f1(x)

Question 2:  f2(x)

with the functions f1(x), f2(x) displayed properly typeset (which "display" provides).

The nearest I've got is with matrices:

```
M = sympy.Matrix([["(a)",f1(x)],["(b)",f2(x)]])
display(M)
```

but this has two problems: (1) it shows the matrix delimiters, and (2) it strips the parentheses from "(a)" and "(b)".

So I'm still hoping for help: how to add a string to a line that uses "display".  Thanks!

Comment: I really wish you had included some of your sympy examples, such as `f1(x)`, even if just toy examples. It would insure my suggestion matches what you are doing better than my guesses.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1: Use `Math()`

I think the easiest would be to combine in the use of `Math()`, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74033885/8508004) and sources therein.

```py
import sympy as sym
from IPython.display import Math
x = sym.symbols('x')
I = sym.integrate(1/(1+x**2), (x, 0, 1))
y = 2
z = 4
Math(rf'\text{{Press 1 to compute }} {x}^{y} \text{{or 2 to compute }} \frac{y}{z} \text{{or something else all togeher different to computer}} {sym.latex(I)}')
```

Related to that is [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56662833/8508004) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56662833/8508004).

That approach somewhat more translated to your example, that would be:

```py
import sympy as sym
from IPython.display import Math
x = sym.symbols('x')
I = sym.integrate(1/(1+x**2), (x, 0, 1))
y = 2
z = 4
display(Math(rf'\text{{Question 1: }} {x}^{y}'))
display(Math(rf'\text{{Question 2: }} {sym.latex(I)}'))
```

#### Option 2: Use markdown with dollar signs to specify Latex

You can get very fancy with a variation on an example I built [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/display-command-output-as-math-ipython-display-math/3125/2?u=fomightez) that includes some sympy use combining markdown and f-strings:

```py
from IPython.display import Markdown, display
def printmd(string):
    display(Markdown(string))
import sympy as sym
x = sym.symbols('x')
I = sym.integrate(1/(1+x**2), (x, 0, 1))
equation = r'$\int_{{t=0}}^1 \frac{{1}}{{1+t^2}}\,\text{d}t$'
printmd('**THE EQUATION:**')
printmd(f'Question 2: {equation}')
printmd('**THE RESULT:**')
printmd(f'Question 1 $  = {sym.latex(I)}$')
printmd('**OR, COMBINED:**')
printmd(f'Question 3: '+equation[:-2] + f' = {sym.latex(I)}$$')
```

I see that is a variation on [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51656837/8508004).

Comment: Thank you, Wayne, and indeed your method works well.  As a toy example (have imported SymPy as sy):

    f = lambda x: x**2+3*x-4
    Math(rf'\text{{Question 1: }} {sy.latex(f(x))}')