# Pretty-print result of Jupyter code cell together with text?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, sage

Is there a way to output text together with the result of a code evaluation in a Jupyter notebook running SAGE as a kernel?

```
A = matrix([[3, 2], [3, 1]])
B = matrix([[5, 4], [4, 7]])
show(LatexExpr('C = A \cdot B = '), A * B)
```

My naive idea was to use

```
show(LatexExpr('\text{Result:} C = A \cdot B = '), A * B)
```

However, this did not give the desired output.

Comment: See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76230099/8508004) to a similar question. (Your question is phrased a bit clearer.) The links therein may also provide you with some guidance.